# Equality in field with characteristic p

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume that $F$ is a field with characteristic $p$. How I can prove that in this field if we have $x^p=y^p$ then this implies that  $x=y$ for any $x,y\in F$.

Comment: The Frobenius endomorphism is [injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1181490/frobenius-injective-for-finite-fields-what-about-mathbbf-pn).

Comment: I'd add that every field homomorphism is injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In characteristic $p$, $x^p-y^p=(x-y)^p$. So $x^p=y^p$ implies
$(x-y)^p=0$ implies $x-y=0$ implies $x=y$.

Comment: How do we know that $(x-y)^p=0$ implies $x-y=0$?

Comment: We are in a **field**. @Mayers

Comment: Of course. Stupid question :)